# What is the Zohar's explanation of: "And the children struggled together within her"?

Tags: parashat-toldot, esav, jacob

In Parshat Toldot, Rebecca is pregnant with the twins Esau and Jacob and we read:

> וַיִּתְרֹֽצֲצ֤וּ הַבָּנִים֙ בְּקִרְבָּ֔הּ -- And the children struggled together within her. [Genesis 25:22].

There are many interpretations of this line, but I don't understand this one from the Zohar:

> Why did they struggle? Because the Evil Inclination was abolished from the heart. [[Zohar 1:140b]](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Zohar.1.140b&lang2=bi)

What does it mean?

Comment: This is in the middle of an extended metaphor. The question "why did they struggle?" is about the struggle of the liver and the heart, which are metaphorically read into the struggle of Jacob and Esau. The answer only makes sense when you take into account its context (though admittedly even in its context the answer isn't immediately clear)

Comment: I know, and that's why I asked.

Comment: It might be useful to situate the question in the context of the metaphor rather than in the context of Jacob and Esau for those readers (such as me) who didn't know that the Zohar's answer isn't referring to the literal children

Comment: The heart had no self identity (like Moshe) and therefore could be anything. Hence the struggle.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi "And the children struggled together within her." These are the two foundations of the body: the brain and the heart. I think it ought to be brain and liver. I dont think the translation is 'abolished'. I dont think he means either that the liver and heart 'struggled' with each other.  But the zohar previously says that hashem 'breaks' the heart.

Comment: I mean heart and liver

Comment: HE THEN WONDERED WHY, IF THE EVIL INCLINATION WAS ABOLISHED, IT IS WRITTEN, "Struggled." It should have been written, 'And they were at peace'. Rav Huna explained that "struggled" means that the strength and vigor OF THE HEART AND LIVER, THE LEADERS OF THE BODY, were broken, BECAUSE THE EVIL INCLINATION WAS REMOVED. Rabbi Yehuda asks, What does the body say then? The body asks, 'If it be so, why am I thus?' and 'Why was I created?' Immediately, "she went to inquire of Hashem" (Beresheet 25:22).